# How do I access the underlying struct of a reflect.Value?

Tags: go, reflection

How do I access the underlying (opaque) struct of a reflect.Value (eg, a time.Time) from the reflection library?

So far, I've been creating a temporary time.Time, taking the ValueOf it, then using Set() to copy it out.  Is there a way to access the original directly *as* a time.Time?

Comment: Use `.Interface()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `reflect.Value` that represents a value of type `time.Time`, you can use the `Interface()` method on `reflect.Value` to get the value as an `interface{}` and then do a type assertion to convert it back to `time.Time`.

Here's how you'd typically convert a `reflect.Value` holding a `time.Time` back to a `time.Time`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Timestamp time.Time
    Name      string
}

func main() {
    // Create a MyStruct value.
    s := MyStruct{
        Timestamp: time.Now(),
        Name:      "Test",
    }

    // Get the reflect.Value of the MyStruct value.
    val := reflect.ValueOf(s)

    // Access the Timestamp field.
    timeField := val.FieldByName("Timestamp")

    // Use Interface() to get an interface{} value, then do a type assertion
    // to get the underlying time.Time.
    underlyingTime, ok := timeField.Interface().(time.Time)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get the underlying time.Time")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Underlying time.Time:", underlyingTime)
}
```